# Looged in user action tracked in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

I need a Joomla 1.5 component for performing the following task

when a user logged in all their actions must be tracked,

These actions include:

Date Logged in,
 Time of login,
 Pages visited by login user,
 Time on each page,
 Links clicked by login user,
 Forms submitted,
 Time logged out
 Total Time spent on site for this visit
  and report for all above action

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
http://joomlax.net/downloads/Access---Security/User-Management/User-Trace/

It is quit easy to modify following your needs.

Take into consideration google analytics modules:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/site-analytics-google-based